# a symbol name was expected! (near ")"

Tags: mysql

Please help me, i don't know why! I think this is correct in writing the query. But the following error message appears like this :

> 1. A symbol name was expected! (near ")" at position 164)
> 2. At least one column definition was expected. (near ")" at position 164)

And this is the query :

```
CREATE TABLE `detum` (
`idu` int(12)
,`nik` varchar(10)
,`nama` varchar(35)
,`kdstore` int(4)
,`nmstore` varchar(40)
,`tglmsk` date
,`shift` varchar(4)
,`start` time
,`end` time
,`event` varchar(2)
,`ln` varchar(1)
,`jkerja` decimal(13,4)
,`tjkerja` decimal(13,4)
,`jlembur` decimal(13,4)
,`jlembur1` decimal(15,5)
,`jlembur2` decimal(14,4)
,`jlembur3` decimal(14,4)
,`jlembur4` decimal(14,4)
,`tl` decimal(15,1)
,`gaji` int(7)
,`periode` varchar(7)
,`acc` varchar(1)
);
```

> Lines of code from 141 to 164 in above.

Comment: It runs for me.

Comment: it's works fine in my side,my verison is `5.0.67`

Comment: Position 164 is a character position, not line number. What is at that position?

Comment: Do you have some email guys, let me give you my sql database file. Because when i imported then give my error!